# Excel Macro Help - Stacking Macros

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

I am using the following subroutine to combine multiple Excel files from a single folder into a single workbook with multiple worksheets.

```
Sub Merge2MultiSheets()

Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFilename As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
MyPath = "C:\MyPath" ' <-- Insert Absolute Folder Location
Set wbDst = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "\*.xls", vbNormal)

If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

Do Until strFilename = ""            
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & "\" & strFilename)                
    Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)                
    wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)                
    wbSrc.Close False            
    strFilename = Dir()            
Loop
wbDst.Worksheets(1).Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The end product is an excel file with multiple worksheets (as well as one blank Sheet 1). I was wondering how I can then apply another macro to this newly created Workbook. As an example, I wish for all the worksheets within this new workbook to have their Headers bold and coloured a certain way, and to have the empty Worksheet deleted.

eg:

```
Sub Headers()

Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True
With Selection.Interior
    .ColorIndex = 37
    .Pattern = xlSolid
End With
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sheets.Select       'selects all sheets'
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
```

Comment: iDevlop - I agree this works but my point was that you have to hard code the sheet references and you are assuming that there are only three sheets that are named Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3. To make the code as re-usable as possible (i.e handle indeterminate number of sheets and names) you cannot avoid looping through the sheets...

Comment: @Remnant: I agree with your objection. I don't have time right now, but I'll try to show a proper way. I am quite sure I did that some time ago by referencing the first and last sheet (which you can identify). Just need to find how...or admit I am wrong ;-)

Comment: what would be good if VBA had something like ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Group. By the way, don't view this about who is wrong or right...it's about helpng each other learn and I'd be delighted if you could show me a more efficient way of coding!

Comment: @Remnant: found at least one way to select all sheets at once  :-))
See edit

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to Headers that specifies a sheet, then call the sub somewhere in the Do Loop after the copy, like:

```
Call Headers(wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count))
```

with your second sub looking like this:

```
Sub Headers(workingSheet As Worksheet)

workingSheet.Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True
With Selection.Interior
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the following:

1) First, delete `Sheet1` as you asked for in your post

2) Format the top row in the remaining sheets

```
Sub Headers()
Dim wkSheet As Worksheet

//Delete Sheet1. Note that alerts are turned off otherwise you are prompted with a dialog box to check you want to delete sheet1
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

//Loop through each worksheet in workbook sheet collection
For Each wkSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With wkSheet.Rows("1:1")
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        //Add additional formatting requirements here
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: No need to loop through the worksheets. Just GROUP them, do the job, then UNGROUP them.

Comment: @iDevlop - can you show me some code for this? To group in VBA I thought you had to create an array of worksheets e.g. Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")) but seems to me that to do this you would first need to loop through each worksheet in the workbook to create the array?